# Add " to the end of any line that ends in This or this using sed in unix

Tags: unix

I have a file where a few lines end with `tux`. How do I add `"` to the end of any line that ends in words like `this` or `This`?

Comment: Use `sed`. Please show what you tried and explain why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could visit [this site](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) for more examples and help about using sed in overall. Also check it's "Regular expressions" tab or search the web for something like "unix anchor characters".

For this actual problem, these are the relevant parts of the site:

> Sed has the ability to specify which lines are to be examined and/or modified, by specifying addresses before the command. I will just describe the simplest version for now - the /PATTERN/ address. When used, only lines that match the pattern are given the command after the address. Briefly, when used with the /p flag, matching lines are printed twice:
>
> sed '/PATTERN/p' file
>
> And of course PATTERN is any regular expression.

According to these, you could use a sed command like this to get the lines ending with "this" or "This" in your file, or "tux" if you meant that:

```
$ sed '/[tT]his$/p' yourfile
```

or

```
$ sed '/tux$/p' yourfile
```

For putting the double quotes at the end of these lines, you also need to understand:

- $ has a special meaning (end of the input line) as an anchor character in regular expressions

> ... and the character "$" is the end anchor. The expression "A$" will match all lines that end with the capital A. If the anchor characters are not used at the proper end of the pattern, then they no longer act as anchors. The "$" is only an anchor if it is the last character.

- how to use sed for substitution of characters (see the linked page)

> Sed has several commands, but most people only learn the substitute command: s. The substitute command changes all occurrences of the regular expression into a new value. A simple example is changing "day" in the "old" file to "night" in the "new" file:
>
> $ sed 's/day/night/' newfile
>
> Or another way (for UNIX beginners),
>
> $ sed 's/day/night/' old >new
>
> and for those who want to test this:
>
> $ echo day | sed 's/day/night/'
>
> This will output "night".

After these you can construct your own sed command, knowing that you can use this two parts together in one command like this:

```
$ sed '/[pP]atternAtTheEndOfLine$/s/$/patternToAddToEndOfTheLine/' yourfile
```